# Question on bounding the independence number of complete graph partitions

Tags: graph-theory

Let $E(K_n)=E_1∪E_2∪E_3$ be a partition of the set of all edges of the complete graph $K_n$ on a set $V$ of $n$ vertices into three pairwise disjoint sets. Consider the graphs $G_1=(V,E_2∪E_3), G_2=(V,E_1∪E_3), G_3=(V,E_1∪E_2)$. Let $\alpha(G_i)$ denote the independence number of $G_i$. Is it true that $\alpha(G_1)\alpha(G_2)\alpha(G_3) \geq n$?

I'm not certain if this is true, but it does seem so based on several trials of partitioning small $n$.

Also, are there values of $n$ and specific partitions for which this bound is tight?

Comment: Isn't $\alpha(G_1)$ more simply described as the clique number $\omega(V,E_1)$? And don't the well-known lower bounds for Ramsey numbers show that there are edge colorings with $\alpha(G_i)\le c\log n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Ramsey number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) $R(3,3,3)=17$ means that the edges of the complete graph $K_{16}=(V,E)$ can be partitioned into three classes $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_3$ so that each of the graphs $(V,E_i)$ is triangle-free. In your terms, $\alpha(G_1)=\alpha(G_2)=\alpha(G_3)=2$, so that $\alpha(G_1)\alpha(G_2)\alpha(G_3)=8\lt16=n$.

More generally, the probabilistic method shows that there are edge partitions of $K_n$ into $3$ (or just $2$) classes with $\alpha(G_i)\le c\log n$.